# How to bind variables in stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a stored procedure in snowflake with update command. I need to update a table.Below is the code

```
create or replace procedure sp1(col1 varchar,col2 varchar)
returns varchar not null
as
$$
begin
   execute immediate 'update emp set first_name ='||:col1 || 'where' ||:col2|| 'between 1 and 5';
end;
$$;
```

I am getting the below error

```
call('bob','id');
Syntax error:ENT_ERROR' on line 3 at position 3 : SQL compilation error: (line 28)
syntax error line 1 at position 51 unexpected '1'. (line 28)
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: I already provided the solution. can you tell me why it didn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You should include single-quotes for the varchar value and be careful about the spaces. This one should work:

```
create or replace procedure sp1(col1 varchar,col2 varchar)
returns varchar not null
as
$$
begin
   execute immediate 'update emp set first_name =  ''' || :col1 || '''  where ' || :col2 || ' between 1 and 5';
end;
$$;
```

Comment: @sirisha have you tried my solution? because it works since the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create or replace procedure sp1(col1 varchar,col2 varchar)
returns varchar not null
as
$$
begin
   execute immediate 'update emp set first_name =' + col1 + ' where '+ col2 + 
   'between 1 and 5';
end;
$$;
```

Comment: I have tried this but getting error like "Error: invalid identifier '" update emp set first_name = "' (line 33)"